# Nodejs test giving error when part of the test is modularized into a different function

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs test which has below part

```
const response1 = await request({
    method: HttpMethods.POST,
    path: `/v1/incidents/${emptyIncidentId}/assessments`,
    body: requestBody,
    auth: authentication
  })
```

And its giving the correct response. Now, I am trying to put the above into a separate async function because this gets repeated in many tests. So my function looks like below:

```
const response = doRequest(requestBody, emptyIncidentId, authentication)
```

And the function definition is :

```
async function doRequest (requestBody, incidentId, authentication) {
  return request({
    method: HttpMethods.POST,
    path: `/v1/incidents/${incidentId}/assessments`,
    body: requestBody,
    auth: authentication
  })
```

But this doRequest() call always responds with an empty response body. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here. I checked the passed parameters, they are being passed correctly.

Comment: await doRequest()?

Comment: @Jorg - yes, such a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: if you can add that as a answer, i 'll accept the answer.

Comment: ok hang on......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to call an asynchronous function in this manner is to `await` it:

```
const response = await doRequest(requestBody, emptyIncidentId, authentication)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function try it with `await` keyword. Because of the `request` is asynchronous

```
const response = await doRequest(requestBody, emptyIncidentId, authentication);
```